# regular expression with no more than 3 alphabets concurrently should not accept 1a1a1a1a1

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

should not accept: 1a1a1a1a1, aaaa11111 ,2222aaa33a
only allow 3 characters anywhere no more than three should not allowed
I tried like below but failed

```
var patt = new RegExp("([A-Za-z]){4}");
var result = patt.test(DLnumber);
if (result == true) {
    alert("No more than three alphabets are allowed");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thin this may be what you look for:

```
if (str.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "").length>3) {
    alert("No more than three alphabets are allowed");
    return false;
}
```

It counts the Alphabetical chars in the string...

Answer (score 1):

```
   function testNumberOfChar(str){
    var match= str.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g);
    if( match && match.length > 3 ){
       alert("No more than three alphabets are allowed"); 
       return false;
    }
    return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex needs to account for non-letters in between the letters. I would do that with this regex:

```
^(?!.*([a-z].*){4,}).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xlaFw8Xe83J0BJJ2)

This way you can easily add more requirements by adding another `(?!...)` or `(?=...)` [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){3,}).*$
```

Try this.See demo.The looahead makes sure any character is not there more than 3 times.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/10

```
var re = /^(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){3,}).*$/gm;
var str = '1a1a1a1a1\naaaa11111\n2222aaa33a\nsadsada';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: I think this is overly complicated. If we consider that OP's pattern is `[A-Za-z]`, I think "an alphabet" is any character. I'm guessing we're just asked to check if there are more than three characters, which could easily be tested by checking the number of matches for `/[a-z]/gi`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
if (/^(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){4}/i.test(DLnumber)) {
    alert("No more than three alphabets are allowed");
    return false;
}
```

- the i modifier makes the pattern case-insensitive, so `[a-z]` is the same than `[a-zA-Z]` and `[^a-z]` the same than `[^a-zA-Z]` for all the pattern.
- `^` is the anchor for the start of the string *(not needed but improve performances in particular when the pattern must fail)*
- `(?:...)` is an non-capturing group, *(it does nothing, its only task is to put other tokens together, then you can apply a quantifier to all the group.)*
- `(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){4}` means *a group of zero or more non-letters followed by a letter and repeated 4 times*