# Creating a password

Tags: passwords

Passwords must match and be 6-20 characters in length, and must also contain:
at least one alpha character
at least one number or special character
no more than three repeating characters
please help me out

Comment: 1) reach for your keyboard, 2) type a password matching those requirements.

Comment: Ha ha really. This is a classic

Comment: Most languages can create a random string of letters/numbers. In what language would you need to create a password?

Answer (score 0):

Need three checks, and in the input box put maxlength="20", also you can add more special characters

```
var password = getPassword;
if(password.length <= 6){
 // display error too short
}
else if((/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d_@./#&+-]*$/.test(password) == false){
 // display error must be 1 letter and 1 number or special character
}
else if(password.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "").length>3){
  // display error cannot be 3 alphabet characters repeating 
}
else{
// success 
}
```

check out this solution if u need more from the repeating function

[regular expression with no more than 3 alphabets concurrently should not accept 1a1a1a1a1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718145/regular-expression-with-no-more-than-3-alphabets-concurrently-should-not-accept)